# The database engine couldn't lock the table, because it is already in use by another person or process

Tags: microsoft-access-2003

I tried to do "Split a Database" and after I clicked on the "Split" button, here is what I got: 
"The database engine couldn't lock the table, because it is already in use by another person or process"

Any idea?

Thanks

---

additional question:

is it possible to split your database many times? first i'm trying it at home and the following day i would like to try it at the office if it works. i already tried the split and if i do it tomorrow at the office would that be a problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is an error you typically get when you have the design view open on the table. I'm not sure what the split feature does, but if it moves records back and from separate mdb files, it should work using plain (optimistic) locking like other operations use.

Comment: @Stijn:thanks. is it possible to split your db many times?